# Why is System.Drawing.Rectangle.getWidth() so expensive?

Tags: c#

I am making an SDL program and sometimes I need to get the width of a rectangle. When I do something like this:

```
        int VideoWidth = Video.Screen.Width; //Expensive operation
        int VideoHeight = Video.Screen.Height;

        int ChunksRendered = 0;
        foreach (Chunk c in Chunks)
        {
            if (c.X + 256 + DeferredX > 0 && c.X + DeferredX < VideoWidth)
            {
                if (c.Y + 256 + DeferredY > 0 && c.Y + DeferredY < VideoHeight)
                {
                    BlitSurface.Blit(c.Render(ref Textures, ref BlitSurface), new Point(c.X + DeferredX, c.Y + DeferredY));
                    ChunksRendered++;
                }
            }
        }
```

I get around 550 FPS on my machine, but when I do this:

```
        int ChunksRendered = 0;
        foreach (Chunk c in Chunks)
        {
            if (c.X + 256 + DeferredX > 0 && c.X + DeferredX < Video.Screen.Width)
            {
                if (c.Y + 256 + DeferredY > 0 && c.Y + DeferredY < Video.Screen.Height)
                {
                    BlitSurface.Blit(c.Render(ref Textures, ref BlitSurface), new Point(c.X + DeferredX, c.Y + DeferredY));
                    ChunksRendered++;
                }
            }
        }
```

I only get around 200 FPS. When profiling it's obvious that this causes the slow down, but why is getting this variable so expensive?

Comment: does the screen width change on each frame?

Comment: No it does not but you are able to change resolution while in game

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably it is `Video.Screen` property accessor causing this slowdown. If you are using `SdlDotNet.dll`, here is the code of that property:

```
public static Surface Screen
{
    get
    {
        return Surface.FromScreenPtr(Tao.Sdl.Sdl.SDL_GetVideoSurface());
    }
}
```

It means 1 external dll function is called and 1 `Surface` object is created every time `Video.Screen` property is accessed.

Accessing `Width` or `Height` properties of `Surface` is also expensive as it includes calling following code:

```
internal Tao.Sdl.Sdl.SDL_Surface SurfaceStruct
{
    get
    {
        if (this.disposed)
        {
            throw new ObjectDisposedException(this.ToString());
        }
        GC.KeepAlive(this);
        return (Tao.Sdl.Sdl.SDL_Surface) Marshal.PtrToStructure(base.Handle, typeof(Tao.Sdl.Sdl.SDL_Surface));
    }
}
```

Comment: To add to this answer: The inner if statement is not always executed (the outer if statement's condition can evaluate to false).  That means that in the first example, the Screen property's getter is invoked twice, while in the second, it's invoked Count * (1 to 2) times.  This is sort of a good example of why you should never do something like for(int i = 0; i < object.Value; i++) unless you know that you aren't recomputing Value every time (A better example is using object.GetSomeList()[i] inside of the loop).

Comment: Thanks for that - it was perplexing me, but if it had to recompute the value each time that would explain the slowdown).